# Gitlab CI SOAP tests run

Tags: soap, gitlab, soapui, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Helo,

Is there any way to run Soap/Soap UI tests using Gitlab CI?
I cannot find any clear information about this.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A place to start would be to just mimic the steps you run in a non-ci environment. Then replicate them in the CI.

Have a look at [the topic SoapUI has on this](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html).